# Programatically upload pictures on Instagram workaround

Tags: instagram, photo

How do services like posts.so, gramblr and picturelife post pictures on Instagram programatically?

I know the Instagram API is limited and doesn't let you do this, but is there a workaround? There must be since all these services are doing it.

Links to the services:

https://posts.so/

http://gramblr.com/uploader/

They possibly store your Instagram password in their database then use it to login and use the cookie? That sounds very scary and very illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot upload images via Instagram’s API.**

Per Instagram's API documentation:

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons...

While it is possible to use Instagram's private API to upload photos (you'd need to capture this information using a proxy server) it is a very quick way to get you instantly banned for life from using the API.

There are a handful of exceptions to this rule, Hipstamatic/Oggl being one of them. Whether or not posts.so is or not, I can't say, though I find it highly unlikely that they're authorized to do that they're doing. More-so with gramblr, their site is.. shady at best.

You can read a similar post here: [Uploading photos to Instagram via your own iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242610/uploading-photos-to-instagram-via-your-own-ios-app)

Comment: Thanks. But, how could I capture this information? Sniffing outgoing traffic from an Android device? Any links/tools on how to do this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rightfully suggest that (it's really **strongly** against the TOU). But you google around, you'll probably find something.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a valid web cookie session, you can POST to https://www.instagram.com/create/upload/photo/

This is reverse-engineering on the mobile web upload, and is not recommended. Buy hey if you want to hack something... have fun!