# Share image on Instagram from web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

We have a requirement where we need to share the image to instagram. We are developing an web appication and storing the image as png. The image is located as a physical file in the webserver.

Is there any API where we can directly use the API and upload the image to Instagram or any alternate way where we can share the Image on Instagram?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [this](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

As stated in their developers overview, you need to register for your developer account then authenticate it to start making requests to their endpoints.

As for their libraries, they only have Python and Ruby [here](https://instagram.com/developer/libraries/) 
But I'm sure there's plenty of other libraries in some repository in github.

It is also stated in their api docs that you cannot post photos through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the instagram api: https://instagram.com/developer/

And a previously asked question: [Programatically upload pictures on Instagram workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527066/programatically-upload-pictures-on-instagram-workaround)

Unfortunately, to answer your question, it seems that there is no way to upload images to instagram using their api. [Another related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242610/uploading-photos-to-instagram-via-your-own-ios-app) points out that those apps that do upload directly to instagram have had to get special permission to do so.